# Contextual filters multiple value title

Tags: views, 7

I've added title override %1, to contextual filter. Filter uses taxonomy to get nodes.

If I open page "catalog/1" I get title from term1 with all the content
If I open page "catalog/2" I get title from term2 with all the content
But if I try "catalog/1+2" I get title "No name" and the content for both terms.

How to define page title as title of first (any) term in the filter?

---

Upd it appears that there's a problem with title override. If I add title override %1, then I have "No name" title for multiple terms...

Answer (score 0):

Go to your View. In Contextual filter configuration >> More >> Check "Allow multiple values". So if selected this, users can enter multiple values in the form of 1+2+3

[image]

Comment: I have it selected.
And it works, but resulting page will have "No name" title. 
And this option is not inside "More" it is just allmost at the top of contextual filters.